# Comparing dates across tables in DB2 using CHECK?

Tags: database, db2, constraints

I'm trying to ensure to compare a date within table A to another date in table B where both tables are related by an identifier C.

However, I can't find anything on DB2 as to how to do this. Basically, in pseudocode I'm trying to achieve the following:

```
CONSTRAINT checkDates CHECK (firstDate >= secondDate) WHERE secondDate = tableB.secondDate
```

Is there an easy way to make this work?

For reference, the tables are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA
(
identifier CHARACTER(254) NOT NULL,
firstDate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE TableB
(
identifier CHARACTER(254) NOT NULL,
secondDate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
)
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I think you would need a user-defined function for this.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Is that easy to do? I'm really not quite familiar with DB2 beyond simple CHECK's and queries?